low FPS and graphical errors in source games (TF2, hl2, Gmod)
To start, here are my PC's specs.
CPU is an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T5750
4 GB of RAM
No dedicated graphics card (graphics driver is Mesa Intel(R) 965GM (CL)) but that shouldn't matter as TF2 is more CPU reliant than GPU…
Now to address the problem.
When I boot TF2 (or any other source games like Gmod or hl2 but TF2 is my main concern) I get low fps (average of 4 fps). After messing around with the launch options to try to fix it it booted in using openGL with 30-60 fps but had strange graphical errors, those red rectangles rapidly flash on every letter.
Then opening TF2 again, it had the same fps issue and the graphical issue despite still being openGL.
I've tried launching in Vulcan, open gl,and direct 3D. Opening in direct 3D fixes the graphical issues but my fps is still cooked.
What is the cause of these graphical issues and how would I fix both the FPS issues and the Graphical issues?
I'm pretty sure that the computer is capable of running it because of the time that I ran with 30-60 FPS so I would greatly appreciate a solution. Also, unrelated, but I experience a similar issue on GZDoom 
